# How to use file upload in devextreme

Tags: javascript, jquery, devextreme

```
var fileInput = $('#files');
var uploadButton = $('#upload');
uploadButton.on('click', function () {
    if (!window.FileReader) {
        alert('Your browser is not supported')
    }
    var input = fileInput.get(0);
    // Create a reader object
    var reader = new FileReader();
    if (input.files.length) {
        var textFile = input.files[0];
        reader.readAsText(textFile);
        $(reader).on('load', processFile);
    } else {
        alert('Please upload a file before continuing')
    }
});


 function processFile(e) {
        var file = e.target.result,
            results;
        if (file && file.length) {
            results = file.split("\n");
            console.log(results)
            $('#name').val(results[0]);
            $('#age').val(results[1]);
        }
     }



<input type=file id=files />
<button id=upload>Upload</button>
<br/><br/>
<input type=text id=name /><br/>
<input type=text id=age />
```

The above code to upload the file and print the contents of the file in the textbox is done. There is no error in the above code but the devextreme mobile upload button does not work. why could it be?

I'm sorry for my bad english

Comment: There isn't the code that uploads a file, so that's why it doesn't work. You have to add a server-side code to upload files. This [article](https://js.devexpress.com/Documentation/16_2/Guide/Widgets/FileUploader/Upload_Files/Server-Side_Implementation_in_PHP/) shows how to do it with PHP.

Comment: @Sergey  
Hi,thank you. I try this.      
js.devexpress.com/Demos/WidgetsGallery/Demo/File_Uploader/… How to read this in text file?

Comment: @Sergey http://jsfiddle.net/AjaDT/2/ but not working devextreme